# How to find which time value is the oldest?

Tags: vb.net

In my project, at some point I tend to load all rows in my DataSet and add them to my FlowLayoutPanel in order of their "Time" Item. This is what I'm trying to do but I need the controls to be added first if their "Time" value are the oldest :

```
For i=1 to DataSet.Tables("myTable").Rows.Count
 Dim Row as Datarow = DataSet.Tables("myTable").Select("ID = " & i)
 Dim Time as Date = Row.Item("Time")
 Dim NewLabel as Label
 NewLabel.text = Time.ToString()
 FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(newLabel)
Next
```

How do I do that ?

Comment: Why don't you sort the rows with your query and then go through your rows in order?

Comment: I use Access .mdb file. Will it work if I sort it inside access? Won't the rows get re-sorted after the startup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
Dim timeOrderedRows = From row in DataSet.Tables("myTable")
                      Order By row.Field(Of Date)("Time")
For Each row As DataRow In timeOrderedRows
    Dim Time as Date = row.Field(Of Date)("Time")
    Dim Label as New Label
    Label.text = Time.ToString()
    FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(Label)
Next
```

> How can I do this in reverse (from newest to the oldest)

You just have to add `Descending`:

```
....
Order By row.Field(Of Date)("Time") Descending
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Works like a charm. How can I do this in reverse (from newest to the oldest) ?

Comment: @Boher: Then add `Descending`. Edited my answer.

Comment: to which expression exactly ?

Comment: Opps :D Thanks a million.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a `Dim NewLabel As New Label`?